# Avoid having the web-menu reload each time the user clicks a link?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm working on an ASP.net web application.  The application has a menu of link buttons at the top that appears exactly the same on every page.

My customer's representative pointed out to me that the menu "flashes" each time a link is clicked as the screen goes blank and the next page is loaded.

Right now, I'm using a master page to make the menu the same on every page.  I am aware that frames are another way to accomplish this.  If I were to put the menu in a frame, it would not reload every time the user clicks a link.

It is also possible, but not really feasible, to do this with client side scripting.

Do any of you fellow stackers know of a good way (not frames) to have a menu on every page in a web application that does not "flash" each time a new page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET way is to put the entire site body in an `UpdatePanel`, and make all navigation  with postback controls.

Generally speaking, the only way to truly accomplish this (other than frames, which is a terrible idea) is to use AJAX to load the body of each page. `UpdatePanels` do this.

Your customer must be using IE8. Chrome and Firefox do a nice job of not making elements that remain unchanged between navigation stay on the screen.

Tell them to go to Amazon.com and click on a few links. Same thing (in IE anyway).

Comment: Because UpdatePanels and postbacks aren't a terrible idea?

Comment: It depends on your definition of terrible. Sure, `UpdatePanels` are an absurdly inefficient way to accomplish an ajax query, but at the end of they day, they will render the same thing. I'm not going to stand here and say that UpdatePanels are the best way to do ajax, but for an existing asp.net site, it would be pretty easy to do this. Changing it to a completely different architecture would basically be starting over. Frames are a different kind of terrible.

Comment: Sorry, I came out a bit offensive. All I meant to say was that UpdatePanels create horrible ajax and doing something like this would probably be my last option EVER (including doing something with jquery, which shouldn't be TOO hard)... I just felt that you didn't say how terrible UpdatePanels are for perfomance. Indeed it is probably that fastest to implement...

Comment: I'm having a hard time making the comparison between AJAX and `UpdatePanel`. From my understanding, if we use a server side link, when the user wants to go to another page they will have to post back to the same page before being redirected to the next. So you end up incurring all of the original http requests that weren't needed to jump to the page.

Comment: True, they're resource hogs, but on the server. In this day and age, server performance is rarely a problem, and it's one that you're usually glad you have. The reality is they work perfectly well in most situations, and unless you're amazon.com, it would be unlikely to create a bottleneck. (It could easily make your web site appear faster, too, since much less data is being transferred on each page load). Sometimes a technically inferior, but far easier to implement, solution is the best one. Especially if the alternative is a total redo.

Comment: `UpdatePanels` = AJAX in a huge layer of microsoft abstraction. A "partial postback" is an asynchronous AJAX request. On the server, of course, it runs the entire page code from start to finish, but the framework extracts just the part in the "updatepanel" and only updates that part on the client. In jQuery, the equivalent would be using $.load to pull up all the HTML for page's own self, and then pulling out the contents of the DIV you wanted to update. (Well, sorta, since an UpdatePanel wouldn't actually send the whole page back to the client, but it still processes the whole thing.)

Comment: @jamietre that's not true. They are also a burdon on the client as they send a lot of useless information (i/e ViewState etc) which can create very large requests

Comment: `ViewState` has nothing to do with `UpdatePanels`. You can have horrendous viewstate without them, and you can use UpdatePanels with no viewstate.

Comment: @jamietre using a jquery.ajax you have a clean request (just URL/cookies) when you load a page. Maybe this has been fixed (I haven't used an updatepanel for a while) however the last time that I used an updatepanel it would post the whole request to server including ViewState which *could* make it a very large request and as such - slower (sometimes much slower) than jquery.ajax and that's why it's a burden on the client as well as on the server...

Comment: @Linkgoron what I'm saying is that `ViewState` is part of any ASP.NET postback, and not specifically related to using an UpdatePanel. To the extent that you would be using POST for navigation, then yes, it is a concern. However if your site uses ViewState in places where it's not needed, that's a different problem. I realize it's a common one, since it is enabled by default, and I blame Microsoft for jigabytes of wasted bandwidth for that decision. But if you have ViewState disabled on your site except for elements where it actually does anything it should not matter at all.

Comment: To be clear I absolutely do not disagree that using a client-based ajax architecture is almost certainly going to be more efficient. But the OP is talking about an existing ASP.NET site (which I assume is designed around a server-controlled architecture). To change that to a client/async controlled architecture would be a total redesign. With very little effort it could likely be done with UpdatePanels. I'm sure it wouldn't be quite as efficient but would anyone notice? As long as there's not massive viewstate abuse, probably not.

Comment: @jamietre this is true (ViewState is a part of every postback), but from what I understand currently he has links (as in anchor tags) between pages, which don't carry the burden of ViewState (because they're not postbacks). I don't know how he's setup his site, however if he hasn't set his ViewState correctly using an updatepanel you might kill his performance for the sake of a flashing header.

Comment: I agree, I was just answering the question. As I said, the best solution is to tell his client to point his browser at Amazon.com which (like most non-super-modern web sites) also flickers in IE.

Comment: @jamietre sorry for this long discussion, or if I came out a bit offensive, I just felt you didn't stress enough the dangers that come with UpdatePanels. BTW, creating a pure jquery solution shouldn't actually be that hard IMO, but that's another discussion.

Comment: I enjoy these kinds of discussions :) I can't think of many scenarios where a total architecture change would be easy. If every page was just static content, and it was in a CMS, then maybe. But ASP.NET forms don't work with non-asp.net AJAX.

Comment: @jamietre I'm talking about hijaxing navigation between pages (basically only the GET requests), which using some class selectors *shouldn't* (famous last words...) be too difficuly. o/c this depends on the architecture and how stuff is organized. This isn't about fixed grid paging etc, which would be much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

"My customer's representative pointed out to me that the menu "flashes" each time a link is clicked as the screen goes blank and the next page is loaded."

You need to find a new customer representative that understands the basics of how the internet works.

Barring that, you can use Frames (which you don't want to use, as that's bad).

Or you could have one page that loads the menu, then all of the content on the page would then be instead loaded via AJAX calls. But you don't want to use that either, as that's silly.

So, yea, get a new customer representative. ;)

Comment: I think he does understand how the internet works.  I was just wondering if there might be some new trick out there to do this that I haven't heard of yet.

Comment: If they know how the web works, then maybe you need to figure out exactly what they are describing. Otherwise, what they are asking for sounds like the basic premise of the web...click a link, a new page loads, wiping out the old page. That's how its always worked. Some browsers are better at the visual transition between pages, but it's been that way for a long time now.

Comment: @DA, there are several instances of webpages where the menu is not reloaded and simply the content is reloaded. Also, if the customer IS NOT SUPPOSED to understand how the web works, it's the developer who is supposed to understand it.

Comment: @Parijat as I state, yes, you could do it all via AJAX or the like. I disagree that a customer isn't supposed to know how the web works, but certainly the job of the developer is to help educate. In this case, the solution is to educate the client as to how this is really a factor of the web browser more than the site and the pros and cons of all the workarounds.